# File system references to Kendo in MVC Layout.cshtml publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, razor, kendo-ui

[image]Though my development environment is working fine, I have not been able to get Kendo or Jquery to load from my Index.cshtml page.

Is there sometihng wrong witn my references.

[image: My Server Directory Structure and Browser errors]

[image: This is my servers folders along with the errors generated from the site]

Comment: if you copy one of the failed url and paste it in url does it open js file in browser?

Comment: It doesn't find it.   I get a 404 File Not Found in the Element Inspector

Comment: Do you have anything like URLScan running on your web server as this may be blocking the files inadvertently.